# How to return two 2d arrays from a function JavaScript Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, return-value

I have a function that produces two 2d arrays; how do I return both of them?

I can return two 1d arrays

```
function test() {
  do some stuff and get
  arr1 =["A',"B","C"]
  
  do some other stuff and get
  arr2 =["X","Y","Z"]


  return [arr1,arr2]
}
```

test[0]= arr1

test[1]=arr2

But if I have

```
function test() {
  do some stuff and get
  ary1 =[
         ["A',"B","C"],
         ["M',"N","O"]
        ] 
         

  do some other stuff and get
  ary2 =[
         ["X","Y","Z"],
         ["M',"N","O"]
        ] 
  return [ary1,ary2]
}
```

and I get

test[0] =["A',"B","C"]

test[1] =["X","Y","Z"]

Expected result:

```
test[0] =[
          ["A',"B","C"],
          ["M',"N","O"]
         ]

test[1] =[
          ["X","Y","Z"],
          ["M',"N","O"]
         ] 

how do I return ary1 and ary2?
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your expected values. So, when the values of `ary1` and `ary2` of your 2nd script are used, what are your expected values?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I update my question

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I posted an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your script, `test` of `test[0]` and `test[1]` is the function. So, in this case, please modify `test()[0]` and `test()[1]`.

```js
function test() {
  ary1 = [["A", "B", "C"], ["M", "N", "O"]];
  ary2 = [["X", "Y", "Z"], ["M", "N", "O"]];
  return [ary1, ary2];
}

console.log(test()[0]);
console.log(test()[1]);
```

#### Note:

- As additional information, in the case of `test()[0]` and `test()[1]`, the script of `test()` is run 2 times. So, in this case, I thought that the following sample might be suitable.

```js
function test() {
  ary1 = [["A", "B", "C"], ["M", "N", "O"]];
  ary2 = [["X", "Y", "Z"], ["M", "N", "O"]];
  return [ary1, ary2];
}

const values = test();
console.log(values[0]);
console.log(values[1]);

// or the following sample can be also used.
const [a, b] = test();
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I swear I tried that initially, and it did not work!! But now it does. Thank you for your kind reply